# How to create a type for any string value that is located in array of objects by property name?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

```
interface Icon {
    id: number,
    className: string,
    tags: string[]
}

const iconArr = [
  {
      id: 1,
      className: 'banana-class',
      tags: ['']
  },
  {
      id: 2,
      className: 'apple-class',
      tags: ['']
  }
];
```

I would like to create a `type` that will cause an error if any other value other than `banana-class` or `apple-class` is written.

In array of strings i would use `type iconStringType = typeof iconStringArr[number]`, but in my case i have an array of objects.

Thanks!

I tried using:

```
type iconType = typeof iconArr[number]['className'];
```

but it doesn't work - it allows any string value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't type you `iconArr` array so the type `iconArr[number]['className']` is inferred as `string` regardless of your `Icon` interface.

This can easily be fixed by explicitly setting the `Icon[]` type like:

```
const iconArr: Icon[] = [
    ...
];
```

Then if you want to be strict on the allowed strings in your `className` you could create a union type `'banana-class' | 'apple-class'` and use it in your `Icon` interface:

```
interface Icon {
    id: number,
    className: 'banana-class' | 'apple-class',
    tags: string[]
}
```

Now your `type iconType = typeof iconArr[number]['className']` will evaluate to the union type you created.

**Edit after clarification in comments:**

If you want the `Icon` type inferred at runtime you can:

```
const iconArr = [
  {
      id: 1,
      className: 'banana-class' as const,
      tags: ['']
  },
  {
      id: 2,
      className: 'apple-class' as const,
      tags: ['']
  }
];

type Icon = typeof iconArr[number];

type iconType = typeof iconArr[number]['className'];
```

Defining e.g. `'apple-class' as const` tells Typescript to infer the "narrowest type" which in your case is `'banana-class' | 'apple-class'` ([see docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions))

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

You almost given me the answer i was looking for.
Yes I would like to be strict and allow only specific strings, but i would like for union to automatically update when another object is added to the array.

ex. If i add `{id: 123, className: 'new-class', tags: []}`, i would like for `new-class` value to be automatically used in a "union" - if this approach is possible.

If not, is the second best option to manually add strings to "union".

Comment: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIIPYmQbwFDKHLAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtADQFEIA2cAzpwHJw0QKAcjpwQYuAFp2XTkOQAfZELgAHVWwjSO3IcyLIwcAOacKnMFFDGA2gF08AXzx5MIC8TcBBKFAo+oOABPAB50LAA+ZABeZBsWfANCUgoARn0kmW4+AWFRcXFtWT0WAyNTChshIQdCRwzEpJTkACYMgyzefkFlNQ0tTpKkwxMzOOra5HrSxoNmgGZ21h0u3OVVCDgoIt0lwnKxqpqWZzsAbiA)

Comment: @Nixt I updated my original answer taking into account your comment. Let me know if this solves it!